# Java - Efficient regex to match date and time

Tags: java, regex

Example String:

> 00000018.000f1b1f 0101559e Thu May 19 2016 00:24:14 -05:00 [k....

... mentions unwanted words.

There is no specification like `Thu` always be third string if we delimit by space. It can be anywhere in the string. I want to match `Thu May 19 2016 00:24:14 -05:00` and parse with `simpedateformat` class.

I am thinking some regex like `.*?((sun|mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat)\s* (jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\s+\d{0,2}\s+\d{0,4}\s+\d{0,2}\:\d{0,2}\:\d{0,2}\s+([+|-]\d{0,2}:\d{0,2})?).*?`

I am not good at regex. Please help me to improve my regex which can be easily parsed by `simpledateformat` class. `-05:00` is optional.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your expression looks fine to me if you use case insensitive flag. Just `[+|-]` must be replaced with `[+-]`. No need to escape `:`. And if you use `matcher.find`, no need using `.*?` at the start/end.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah Sure. I 'll be using `matcher.find`. I will avoid and ll include case insensitive flag. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex looks OK, but you can improve performance by restricting the search to single spaces and fixed number of digits

`(?i)\b((sun|mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat) (jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec) \d{1,2} \d{4} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}( [+|-]\d{2}:\d{2})?)`

Then you can search on it in a loop (`while (matcher.find()) ...`)

Keep in mind though that a date format depends on the application locale. Expecting a certain format will make your application fragile.

Comment: Thanks for fixed length improvement.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use regex, then you can rely on the fact the SimpleDateFormat will ignore stuff after the match, so the below will work

```
    String in = "00000018.000f1b1f 0101559e 2016/12/14 12:34 [k....";

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");

    while (in.length() > 0)
    try {
        System.out.println(df.parse(in));
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception ee) {
        in = in.substring(1);
    }
```

**Note**

Of course change the above mask to that of what is required

Comment: That is exactly what the code does.  Notice the `break`

Comment: I have to go with regex. It does what is expected. Thanks

Comment: Relying on exceptions during normal processing is bad practice. In the past throwing an exception was a very expensive operation. Nowadays it is improved, but not to a point that it is negligible.

Comment: @RustyX Absolutely agree

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to support all 3 date formats? 
i.e:

```
dd.mm.yyyy - European (day-of-month, month, year)
mm/dd/yyyy - US (month, day-of-month, year)
yyyy-mm-dd - Scandinevian (year, month, day-of-month)
```